# Process for syncing branches between git remotes

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull, git-remote

I am working on my own copy of a git repo called buildroot. I created a copy of the repo on the free bitbucket server. I am trying to periodically sync my private repo from the mainline buildroot repo.

I pulled down the local copy to my PC using

```
git clone https://my_user@bitbucket.org/my_user/buildroot.git
```

Then I added the mainline buildroot repo as a remote

```
git remote add mainline https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
```

`git remote -v` now looks like this

```
mainline    https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot (fetch)
mainline    https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot (push)
origin      https://my_user@bitbucket.org/my_user/buildroot.git (fetch)
origin      https://my_user@bitbucket.org/my_user/buildroot.git (push)
```

I can pull the changes from as single branch (such as master) on the `mainline` remote and these changes show up in my `origin` repo after a `git push`

```
get pull mainline master
git push
```

However, new branches never show up on my `origin` repo. Do I have to explicitly checkout each one of these from `mainline` and then push to `origin` or is there a better way to do this?

As seen below, my private repo is missing branches 2018.02.x and 2018.05.x

```
git branch -a

* master
remotes/mainline/2017.02.x
remotes/mainline/2017.05.x
remotes/mainline/2017.08.x
remotes/mainline/2017.11.x
remotes/mainline/2018.02.x
remotes/mainline/2018.05.x
remotes/mainline/master
remotes/mainline/next
remotes/origin/2017.02.x
remotes/origin/2017.05.x
remotes/origin/2017.08.x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

> Do I have to explicitly ... push to `origin`

Yes, but not quite the way you are thinking.  Still, that may be the most convenient.

#### Long

Every Git repository is an independent entity.  Remotes (as in your own repository) or fork linkages (as in a GitHub or Bitbucket fork) record the identity of another Git repository, but the two repositories remain separate entities.  As such, each has *its own* branches, not shared with any other Git repository.

What *is* shared with other Git repositories, but only at "sharing time" (`git fetch` and `git push`), are the *commits*.  These are shared using their raw hash IDs.  This is also where branch names really enter the picture, though, because a Git repository *finds* its commits by its branch names (and other references, but we'll concentrate only on branch names here).

Remember that the role of a branch name in a Git repository is to contain the hash ID of the *last* commit that is to be considered "on" that branch, i.e., the *tip commit* of the branch.  When you use `git checkout branch` followed by an eventual `git commit`, your Git:

- builds the new commit
- while setting the new commit's *parent* hash ID to the current commit hash ID
- then writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the current *name*

so that the branch name once again points to the latest (tip) commit.  That tip commit points backwards to the previous tip, which points backwards to another earlier commit, and so on.

Hence, what `git push` does is:

- hand over some commit(s) that, ideally, simply extend some existing branch(es), then
- requests that the other Git set *its* branch name(s) to remember the tipmost commits of these added commits.

(Extending a branch like this is a *fast-forward* operation.)

If the new commit(s) *don't* just extend some existing branch(es), those particular name-update(s) must be "forced": the other Git will just say no to those update requests that are not fast-forward operations and are not forced.

There is, however, no requirement that these branch-name value changes correspond to any actual branch name(s) in your own repository.  For instance, consider the common (for me at least) case where I am working on some feature and I write a half dozen or more commits.  Out of these, I determine that one is definitely-for-sure a good idea, so I run `git rebase -i feature` and put that one up front.  Then I may run:

```
git push origin <hash>:for-review
```

and make a pull request based on `for-review`.  Pictorially, what I have in my own repository at this point looks like this:

```
...--o--o   <-- origin/feature
         \
          *   <-- origin/for-review
           \
            o--o--o--o--o   <-- feature
```

Five of the six commits remain unpushed; only one, marked `*` here, has been pushed, to the name `for-review` on the repository at `origin`.  Yet I can continue working in my own repository on my `feature` branch, which is six commits ahead of `origin/feature` and five commits ahead of `origin/for-review`.  I just need to be careful to remember that commit `*` is now shared (which is easy enough: it has an `origin/` name that can reach it).

This brings us to what you have to do in your own repository, in order to transfer commits from the Git repository at `mainline` over to the repository at `origin`.  First you must obtain the commits (and their tip-pointing names) from `mainline`:

```
git fetch mainline
```

Now you have all the *commits*; now you can update `origin` using, e.g.:

```
git push origin mainline/2018.05.x:2018.05.x
```

which will send any commits that `origin` does not have, but does need, to make this work, followed by creating the name `2018.05.x` on `origin`, pointing to the same commit as your own `mainline/2018.05.x`.

This is admittedly all a little messy—but the point is that you don't have to have a *branch name* for the commits, as long as you have *some* name by which you (and your Git) can find the commits in your own repository.  To *send* those commits *to* another Git, you can `git push` them by hash ID, or `origin/whatever` name, or you can create a branch name, or do whatever you like as long as it identifies the appropriate tip commit.  On the right-hand side of the `lhs:rhs` name-pair, however, you must provide a name that the Git at `origin` will be OK with creating or updating.

#### Convenience

With `git push` (but not `git fetch`!), if you run:

```
git push origin abc
```

that "means" the same thing as:

```
git push origin abc:abc
```

so it's definitely more *convenient* in many ways to have your own local names for each branch.